motion blur not affecting certain armatured object even in motion in EEVEE (demo video attached)
I'm working on animating character rigs, but i've noticed that some rigged character won't appear to have motion blur even when it's moving. At first i thought it was a material issue, but when i stripped all the material the issue still persists.
However, i've noticed that raising the 'Steps' value in Motion Blur panel will make that object 'appears' to have motion blur but it looks jagged, it's as if that one particular object requires more 'Steps' value than any other object to make it appear to have motion blur.
Any ideas what may have caused this? was there's any obscure options/settings per object that dictates how motion blur should be applied to that object?
Blender 4.1.0
https://youtu.be/lufqp7Xx9a8 (demonstrating the render setting and the resulting bug after render)


It helps a lot if you upload your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

i would really like to, but unfortunately the model used is a paid model and i am not licensed to upload/redistribute the blend file without removing the model
